# awk : search for a keyword in XML and write to another file

Tags: xml, bash, shell, search, awk

My input XML is  below. I need to search in my input XML if "SEARCH" keyword is present. If present, I need to 
copy the contents from `<record>` to `</record>` and write to another XML file.

**Input XML**

```
<XML>
<record category="xyz">
<person ssn="" e-i="E">
<title xsi:nil="true"/>
<position xsi:nil="true"/>
<details>
<names>
<first_name/>
<last_name></last_name>
</names>
<aliases>
<alias>CDP</alias>
</aliases>
<keywords>
<keyword xsi:nil="true"/>
<keyword>SEARCH</keyword>
</keywords>
<external_sources>
<uri>http://www.google.com</uri>
<detail>SEARCH is present in abc for xyz reason</detail>
</external_sources>
</details>
</person>
</record>
<record category="abc">
<person ssn="" e-i="F">
<title xsi:nil="true"/>
<position xsi:nil="true"/>
<details>
<names>
<first_name/>
<last_name></last_name>
</names>
<aliases>
<alias>CDP</alias>
</aliases>
<keywords>
<keyword xsi:nil="true"/>
<keyword>DONTSEARCH</keyword>
</keywords>
<external_sources>
<uri>http://www.google.com</uri>
<detail>SEARCH is not present in abc for xyz reason</detail>
</external_sources>
</details>
</person>
</record>
</XML>
```

**My present code:**

```
NR==FNR {
keywordArray[NR]=$0;
next;
}

/<record / { i=1 }
i { a[i++]=$0 }
/<\/record>/ {
    if (found) {
        for (i=1; i<=length(a); ++i) print a[i] >> output.xml
    }
    i=0;
    found=0
}
$0 ~ "<keyword>"SEARCH"</keyword>" { found=1 }
```

**Issue with current code:**

The code is not searching for "SEARCH" and it is not writing anything to output.xml

**Expected output:**

```
<record category="xyz">
<person ssn="" e-i="E">
<title xsi:nil="true"/>
<position xsi:nil="true"/>
<details>
<names>
<first_name/>
<last_name></last_name>
</names>
<aliases>
<alias>CDP</alias>
</aliases>
<keywords>
<keyword xsi:nil="true"/>
<keyword>SEARCH</keyword>
</keywords>
<external_sources>
<uri>http://www.google.com</uri>
<detail>SEARCH is present in abc for xyz reason</detail>
</external_sources>
</details>
</person>
</record>
```

Comment: Stock advice: don't manipulate XML data with line-oriented tools like `awk`. Use XML-aware tools like `xsltproc` and `xmlstarlet` instead.

Comment: i.e.   xmlstarlet sel -t -m 'XML/record/person/details/keywords/keyword[.="SEARCH"]' -c '../../../..' foo.xml > bar.xml

Comment: @tomc : why is `'../../../..'` required in the above code?

Comment: The code matches the `keyword` element and then selects the `record` element relative to the match, i.e. the parent of the parent of the parent, etc. However, there are easier ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not perfect but maybe you can improve this:

```
BEGIN {
  FS="\n"        # field separator to enter
  OFS="\n"       # output separator as well
  RS="</record>" # records end at </record>
} 
$0 ~ /<keyword>SEARCH<\/keyword>/'     # print record if SEARCH matched
```

Answer (score 1):

With `xmlstarlet`, you could use this:

```
 xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//record[.//keyword/text()='SEARCH']" foo.xml
```

Comment: @user2488578  as @Michael Vehrs noted the  '../../../..'  in my (deliberately explicit) version is to `-c`opy the xml stanza four parents above where "SEARCH" is `-m`atched.